# Why my spinner doesn't display anything even though i have followed some tutorial?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm working a project, and i want to use spinner in it. Firstly, i try some tutorial on youtube and my code successfully to compile, but the problem is my spinner doesn't show any text. Then, i try another tutorial and find solution for my problem from any resource. But, it still not working.
Then i try to make new project that only contains spinner with the same code, it's working perfectly. I don't know why this is happen.
The different between my project and the new project is, my project have navigation drawer. I don't know, but maybe this is related.
sorry for my bad english

this is my xml code for spinner

```xml
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
```

and this is for my java

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(0, "Choose Station");
        categories.add("Station A (Asrama Mahanaim)");
        categories.add("Station B (Asrama Mamre)");
        categories.add("Station C (Asrama Nazareth)");
        categories.add("Station D (Kantin Lama)");
        categories.add("Station E (Studio)");
        categories.add("Station F (GD 8)");
        categories.add("Station G (GD 9)");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Choose Station")) {
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                //TODO auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
```

this is the output when compiled
[image]

Comment: It should be `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,categories);`  . You forget to pass the dataset ..

Comment: You forget to add your list to adatper.

Comment: instead of relying on some tutorial I recommend looking at the official docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner

Comment: I have been tried that, but it's still not working. Thanks for replying by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add list in adapter, Replace code with below

```
ArrayAdapter spinner= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
spinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinner);
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I have been tried that, but it's still not working. Thanks for replying by the way

Comment: Try to set background of spinner and check it again.

Comment: I have been trying a lot, and I have found the problem.

Comment: So, I my project contain LoginActivity(have login_layout), NavigationDrawerActivity(have nav_dev_layout) and HomeActivity(contain spinner and have home_layout). Then I set my Navigation Drawer to open home_layout(the first fragment on my navigation drawer). The problem because, when I'm click login button, I set to change activity from LoginActivity to NavigationDrawerActivity. That's make the spinner didn't work, because my app still in NavigationDrawerActivity but the interface of the app is showing home_layout. So, I want to ask how to make the HomeActivity active?